# How to add Responsive.css in Custom Wordpress Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I am new to wordpress. I have created a wordpress theme which has `style.css` , `header.php` and `index.php` and `footer.php`. Now I want to make my `index.php` page responsive because after resizing of browser window layout of index.php went horrible(doesn't view properly on mobile and other handle held devices).

I want to make index.php responsive with the help of `@media` query or bootstrap.

Please suggest how i can make index.php a responsive page?

Comment: Use media query. Give id and class to HTML element. Media query is good way for fresher to make site responsive.

Comment: ok . how link responsive.css page with custom wordpress page . Code to Link style.css with custom wordpress is : "<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>" type="text/css">" so how i can link responsive css with page .

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your responsive.css sheet using the [wp_enqueue_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)  function inside your functions.php file inside your theme folder. If you don't have this file, just create it :

```
<?php

// Enqueue your files
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    // If the current page is the homepage, then load the responsive.css file
    if(is_home()) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css' );
    }
}

// Add action
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', 15 );
```

Then you need to create your `theme/css/responsive.css` file and write you media queries and styles.

Hope this helps !

Comment: ok . how link responsive.css page with custom wordpress page . Code to Link style.css with custom wordpress is : "<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>" type="text/css">" so how i can link responsive css with page

Comment: Edited the answer : You can try using the `is_home()` function to check if the current page is the homepage